# How can I stream multiple file using live555 concurrently?

Tags: video-streaming, vlc, live555

I am new to live555. I had created a server using live555 by using the "live555MediaServer" command. in client side I am able to stream .h264 file using VLC successfully following the command at client side: vlc rtsp://10.117.180.102:8554/.

If I have two .h264 files, how can I stream them concurrently using VLC player? Is it possible to stream `n` number of files concurrently using live 555? Also, can I stream live video using a camera using live555 library?